# Android startActivity() isn't working inside for-loop

Tags: android, start-activity

I really can't see the problem on my code.
 
The **startActivity()** method is not working in the code below.

Even **Toast.makeText()** does not work.
If I put the toast before the for-loop it works, but I cannot put startActivity before for-loop because there's a error.

```
    //I think nothing special here
    case R.id.bGeneral:
        break;
    case R.id.bProfessional:
        type = "professional";
        new loadQuestioners().execute(type);

        break; 

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pDialog.dismiss();
        int success;
        try {
            success = result.getInt(TAG_SUC);
            if (success == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        result.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            } else if(success == 1){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getString("message"),                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //When I put it here it work
                MyClass addQuest = new MyClass();
                JSONArray jarray = result.getJSONArray("assessments");
                for (int x = 0; x < jarray.length(); x++) {
                    JSONObject j = jarray.getJSONObject(x);
                    String question = j.getString("Ass_Quesion");
                    String a = j.getString("Ass_Opt_A");
                    String b = j.getString("Ass_Opt_B");
                    String c = j.getString("Ass_Opt_C");
                    String d = j.getString("Ass_Opt_C");
                    String answer = j.getString("Ass_Answer");

                    addQuest.addQuestion(question, a, b, c, d, answer);             

                }

                //Toast is also not working here

                Bundle assessmentType = new Bundle();
                Intent questioners = new Intent (Assessments.this, Questioners.class);
                assessmentType.putString("assessmentType", type);
                questioners.putExtras(assessmentType);
                startActivity(questioners);   //NOT WORKING HERE
                finish();


            } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

**UPDATE**
Thx for helping me I findout that I have no error here. I think the error is in here the forloop is not adding the question to my contructor so when my Questioner class get the index of ArrayList on onCreate it make an error.

```
public class MyClass {

private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> questioners = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
private static int col = 0;

public void addQuestion(String question, String a, String b, String c, String d, String answer){
    this.questioners.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    questioners.get(col).add(question);
    questioners.get(col).add(a);
    questioners.get(col).add(b);
    questioners.get(col).add(c);
    questioners.get(col).add(d);
    questioners.get(col).add(answer);
    col++;
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getQuestion(){
    return this.questioners;
}
```

}

Comment: please post the end of the try { block

Comment: `assessmentType.putString("assessmentType", type);`... What is `type`? I don't see it anywhere in the code.

Comment: Check if jarray.length() > 0, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: there should an Exception in the for loop and exception is caught.As a result the code did not execute.

Comment: thx for suggesting to add Exception so know that I find out that I have a big problem haha. actually the error is on the next page Questioners It seems my question is not adding to my contructor myClass

Comment: If you are trying to start an Activity in a loop, you are probably doing things wrong.  If that's really the behavior you need, you'll probably have to re-architect as something like a state machine which can remember what it should do next, and then do that when an event method next runs its code.

Comment: No sir Im use startActivity when the loops end to put all records to my contructor arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `Assessments` class extends `Context`, and `Questioners` extends `Activity`. Also make sure that you added the `Questioners` activity to the **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Comment: Yes sir they all have. public class Assessments extends Activity implements OnClickListener, public class Questioners extends Activity

Comment: My error is on my Contructor the for loop is not adding the questions from php to my contructor ~_~